# How do I resolve this "Could not initialize class org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector" error when autowiring a jaxws:client?

Tags: spring, cxf, jax-ws, autowired, jaxws-maven-plugin

I’m using JBoss 7.1.3.Final, Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE, CXF 2.7.15 and Maven 3.0.3.  I’m trying to autowire a web services client that is generated through the below JAX-WS plugin code …

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>2.1</target>
                <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                <packageName>org.mainco.bsorg</packageName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I attempt to autowire my client using this application context code …

```
<jaxws:client id="orgWebServiceClient"
              serviceClass="org.mainco.bsorg.OrganizationWebService" 
              address="${wsdl.url}" />
```

and this in my service class …

```
@Service("orgWsdlSvc")
public class OrgWsdlServiceImpl implements OrgWsdlService 
{

    …     
    @Resource(name="orgWebServiceClient")
    private OrganizationWebService m_ows;
```

However, when I go to deploy my WAR file, I get this baffling error.  It doesn’t even tell me what the class is causing the NoClassDefFoundError …

```
16:06:55,597 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-16) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orgWebServiceClient': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:618) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934) [spring-context-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410) [spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:89) [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.loadAndRegister(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:243) [cxf-rt-core-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.activateAllByType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:144) [cxf-rt-core-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:126) [cxf-rt-core-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:138) [cxf-rt-core-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus.<init>(SpringBus.java:46) [cxf-rt-core-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.getBusForName(BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java:72) [cxf-rt-core-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.addDefaultBus(BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java:188) [cxf-rt-core-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.JaxWsProxyFactoryBeanDefinitionParser$JAXWSSpringClientProxyFactoryBean.setApplicationContext(JaxWsProxyFactoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:74) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:117) [spring-context-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:92) [spring-context-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:396) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1507) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    ... 19 more
```

What else do I need to do to use my web service client within my Spring @Service class?

**Edit** Per the comment, here is my WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml file ...

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.joda.time" />
            <module name="org.apache.velocity" />
            <module name="org.bouncycastle" slot="main" export="true" />
            <system>
                <paths>
                    <path name="com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl" />
                </paths>
            </system>
        </dependencies>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jpa" />
            <subsystem name="jaxr" />
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
            <subsystem name="webservices" />
            <subsystem name="weld" /> <!-- Prevent WELD-000070 failure -->
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javaee.api" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

To further answer the comments, here is the output requested:

```
LOG.info(ResourceInjector.class.getClassLoader());
ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.myproject.war:main" from Service Module Loader

LOG.info(ResourceInjector.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
vfs:/content/myproject.war/WEB-INF/lib/cxf-api-2.7.15.jar

LOG.info(ExtensionManagerImpl.class.getClassLoader());
ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.myproject.war:main" from Service Module 

LOG.info(ExtensionManagerImpl.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
vfs:/content/myproject.war/WEB-INF/lib/cxf-rt-core-2.7.15.jar
```

Comment: Can you put a full example application on github oder somewhere else? I think this is more classloading-related and not spring-related.

Comment: Unfortunately this is proprietary code and my company wouldn't like me posting it.  I can post my mvn dependency:tree -- would that help?

Comment: Well, create an example with the same problem. Is the missing class available in your application if you try to get it by class.forname()? Is cxf-api.jar on the classpath? Did you run a junit-test? Does the unit-test work? Are you using jboss modules? What is your deployment-structure.xml? Did you put spring into a jboss-module?

Comment: I had those kind of problems on jboss too, but there can be a hell of reasons why it happened.... A running example would make it much easier.

Comment: Hi, I added my jboss-deployment-strcture.xml into my question.  No, I didn't add a spring module to jboss (it is not an option to change our Jboss configuration at this time).  JUnit tests pass (autowiring happens) and yes, I have this file -- /WEB-INF/lib/cxf-api-2.7.15.jar .  However, notice there is no class listed next to the "NoClassDefFoundError".  The exception is "Could not initialize class org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector".

Comment: What is the output of ResourceInjector.class.getClassLoader(), ResourceInjector.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation(), ExtensionManagerImpl.class.getClassLoader() and ExtensionManagerImpl.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() ?

Comment: I added the output at the end of my question.  What is the right way to initialize this ResourceInjector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

> NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector

I would guess that there's a problem with the static initialization in `ResourceInjector` due to class loading issues.

When you look at the [source code of `ResourceInjector`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-bundle-jaxrs/2.7.14/org/apache/cxf/common/injection/ResourceInjector.java#ResourceInjector) you'll notice that it has a static initializer that uses `javax.annotation.Resource`.

I'm am not familiar with jboss class loading or even jboss in general, but I looks like you're excluding `javaee.api` dependencies. Could this by any chance mean that the class loader that's loading the `ResourceInjector` class isn't able to load the `javax.annotation.Resource` class?

**UPDATE**

I've encountered some `NoClassDefFoundErrors` before in a mule application server and it always had something to do with the class loading of the application server. What I would do to track down the problem is open a debugger at line 243 in ´ExtensionManagerImpl`and inspect/query`this.getClass().getClassLoader()`and`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`. This has helped me in the past to solve these kind of problems.

Comment: True I exlude javaee.api, but the javax.annotation.Resource class you mention is included in the $JBOSS_HOME/modules//javax/annotation/api/main/jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar file, which I am not excluding.  Given this, what is your answer recommending I do to fix this?

Comment: Try to add <module name="javax.annotation.api" /> to your jboss-deployment-structure.xml, or whatever name your module.xml containing jboss-annotations.jar has.

Comment: If the `Resource` class is actually available at runtime then I don't have a clue know what the problem might be. The only other static initialization that occurs is the logging but I don't think that the problem.

Comment: Martin, your suggestion about editing the jboss-deployment-structure worked!  If you want to put together an answer, I can accept or I can accept this one.

Comment: I think Pieter earns the bounty for seeing the static initializer.